# Linq lambda query to select child and specify parent data

Tags: entity-framework, linq

I have two tables, `User` and `Group`. I need to select user table and name of the group through lambda expression, and the return type of the method is `User` table

Below is my schema structure for user

[image]

Below is my schema structure for Group table

[image]

Comment: Would you provide code, entities and desired output ?

Comment: Along with user details i need name of the Group.

Comment: Are you using Navigation properties in the user entity ?

Comment: yes we are using

Answer (score 0):

Try something like;

```
        var query = yourContext.Users.Select(user => new
        {
            User = user,
            GroupName = user.Group.Name
        });
```